# How to find trio in list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of lists of the following form :

```py
[[1,2],[2,4],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5],[5,6]]
```

the trio in the list would be :

```py
[2,4,5]
```

formed from the lists : `[2,4], [2,5], [4,5]`

I'm really stuck at this for a long time. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried implementing a dictionary for the same, but wasn't able to proceed after that.

```py
friend_pairs = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(friends_from, friends_to)] #input list
dic = {}
print(friend_pairs)
for a,b in friend_pairs:
    if a in dic:
        dic[a].append(b)
    else:
         dic[a] = [b]
print(dic)
```

I would like to solve the problem without any external libraries such as `networkz`

Comment: What is a formal definition of a _trio_? The example does not seem to explain what it is and especially what it is not.

Comment: It would be a triangle if you construct nodes and edges for the list of lists. You have `[a,b], [a,c] and [b,c]` then `[a,b,c]` is a trio

Comment: What if there are several trios?

Comment: I would like the code to print all of them.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please post your attempt.